# Can I pass a get parameter through CAS server?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

The idea is to pass a get parameter of some kind through cas server, so that before the user has actually authenticated. I tried something like:

```
GET https://<sso:port>/cas/login?service=http://<back-host:port>/verify_ticket&register=http://<back-host:port>/register?param1=123
```

after that a GET request to verify a ticket is executed and my get parameter is lost.

```
GET https://<host:port>/verify_ticket?ticket=DH-9102-<some-stuff>-<sso-host>
```

So is it possible to pass a get parameter so that it wouldn't be lost after ticket verification?

Comment: Are you using jasig cas? To support additional parameters, you need to use SAML.